# How can i get first day and last day of previous month in shell script

Tags: shell, date, unix

In my script i need to get the first day and last day of previous month.
the format should be like
for April month:

**1-April-2014
30-April-2014**

I am very new to unix please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you googled it a little bit? For example http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43264/first-and-last-day-of-a-month helps a lot

Comment: @fedorqui thanks for your replay.I already googled but i can't understood.i need some simple way to achieve this..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have gnu date, then check the following:

#### first day of last month:

```
kent$  date -d"1 $(date -d'last month' +%b)" +%F   
2014-04-01
```

#### last day of last month:

```
kent$  date -d"-1 day 1 $(date +%b)" +%F        
2014-04-30
```